# Reversing a CSV string in a table column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a column in a table which is a varchar(100) containing a single string in CSV format. Numbers only within the range 1->100.
e.g.

```
66,61,47
64
91,82,86,78,88,4,2,15,87,3
69,71,70,97,3,45
```

The order is the reverse of what it should be.
e.g.

```
47,61,66
64
3,87,15,2,4,88,78,86,82,91
etc
```

I know there is a REVERSE operand in MySQL but it reverses the digits.
e.g.

```
REVERSE(47,61,66) = 66,16,74
```

It would work if the digits were limited to the numerical range of 0->9. Not here.

So I'm wondering if MySQL has the equivalent to PHP's explode/implode and array_reverse() which is what I think I'm going to have to fall back on?

Thanks!

Comment: Fix your data structure so a column contains only a *single* value.  Storing lists of ids in a string is a bad, bad idea in a relational database.  The proper structure to use is a junction table.

Comment: I'd say you should store these integers in related table. Its almost never a good idea to store multiple values inside a string field.

Comment: Did my stored procedure help you?

Comment: I've not had time to try it. Since this wasn't to be a regularly used routine but  a "translator" for migrating from an old db to a new one I wrote it in PHP as I said I would and moved on. Since my question got voted up twice I was hoping someone else would check your answer. If not I'll come back to it and try it out when I get a chance. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Why are you wishing to reorder these comma-delimited values?  Did you end up normalising your data storages as recommended?  This page appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Gordon mentioned, I'd recommend normalizing the table. If that is not possible, you could use a rendition of the following stored procedure that can do the trick.

I have created a table for testing:

```
create table test (field1 varchar(100));
-- inserted some data
select * from test
+----------------------------+
| field1                     |
+----------------------------+
| 66,61,47                   |
| 91,82,86,78,88,4,2,15,87,3 |
| 64                         |
| 69,71,70,97,3,45           |
+----------------------------+
```

The objective is to get reverse order after all said and done.

**proc.sql**

The goal of this procedure is to do the following

- Extract first line 66,61,47
- Modify the line so that it looks like (66),(61),(47)
- Create a temporary table to hold these values in order
- Create an insert statement like this: insert into temptable (field1) values (66), (61), (47)
- Extract this data in reverse order. Use group_concat to output the data as 47,61,66
- Update table with this newly received data

Here's the procedure

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists reverse_data//

create procedure reverse_data()
begin

    -- holds modified field1_data and original data
    declare field1_data varchar(100);
    declare field1_orig_data varchar(100);
    declare finished int default 0;

    -- if data was '1,2,3', field1_data will be
    -- (1),(2),(3) so that it can be inserted into
    -- temptable
    declare cursor_csv cursor for
    select
        concat(
            '(',
            replace(field1, ',', '),('),
            ')') as field_data,
        field1
    from test;

    declare continue handler for
    not found set finished = 1;

    -- create a table that will hold ID and each individually
    -- inserted data from the CSV field
    create table if not exists temptable (
        id int auto_increment primary key,
        field1 int
    );
    truncate table temptable;

    open cursor_csv;

    fetcher: loop
        fetch cursor_csv into field1_data, field1_orig_data;
        if finished = 1 then
            leave fetcher;
        end if;

        -- insert data into the temporary table
        set @sql = concat('insert into temptable(field1) values ', field1_data);
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;

        -- extract data from temptable ensuring that reverse order
        -- is selected and group concatenation is done with comma separator
        select group_concat(field1 order by id desc separator ',') into @newdata
        from temptable;

        -- update the table with reverse ordered data
        update test
        set field1 = @newdata
        where field1 = field1_orig_data;

        -- truncate the table so that clean data can be inserted
        truncate table temptable;
    end loop fetcher;

    close cursor_csv;

    -- remove the temporary table
    drop table temptable;

end//

delimiter ;
```

Call the procedure:

```
call reverse_data();
```

Result:

```
select * from test
+----------------------------+
| field1                     |
+----------------------------+
| 47,61,66                   |
| 3,87,15,2,4,88,78,86,82,91 |
| 64                         |
| 45,3,97,70,71,69           |
+----------------------------+
```

If it doesn't work, create a table called templogger with one field called field1 varchar(500). In strategic locations in the stored procedure, insert information into templogger about the variables that are populated.